# Year In Review - Facebook Graph / FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get all of the info used by FB in Year In Review (for a specific year) - all at once? Rather than merging by calling various Graph API calls and filter accordingly. Is there a direct way to get complete Year In review of any friend of mine?

Eg:

```
/me/yearInReview/2012/friendID ?
```

Comment: Did you see documentation suggesting that the 'year in review' feature had a corresponding API? I don't believe it does

Comment: I didn't find it anywhere.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Igy, there was never documentation anywhere that stated this was an API call. This is not possible

Comment: Yeah I knew it was not possible and there wasn't any documentation. Thanks anyway. :)